# HighCharts specific symbol on mouse hover

Tags: highcharts

I would like to show a different symbol on each poitn of a spline graph, only on mouse hover.

I put :

```
plotOptions: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
            },
```

and

```
series: [{
   name: 'Moyenne',
   data: [{
            x:1351731635000, 
            y:1.0, 
            marker: { 
               symbol: 'url(http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/N.png)'
            }, 
            name: 'MISTRAL (315)'
           },{
            x:1351735233000, 
            y:1.5, 
            marker: { 
               symbol: 'url(http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/SE.png)'
           }]
```

And it has no effect unless i put marker enabling to true (and marker always displayed).
I tryied each combination, to put the enabling value in each point data with no effect.

Is anybody able to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using marker option of series object Here is an example which is modified from the example of the api:

```
series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 316.4, 294.1, 195.6, 154.4],
            marker: {
                symbol: 'triangle'
            }
        }, {
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
              symbol: 'url(http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
            },
            data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
        }]
```

> Demo http://jsfiddle.net/km67w/18/

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but it's not exactly my goal. i want a different picture for each point. Indeed, i have to define symbal in the data array. It is working for permanent pictures but not for hover

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/km67w/40/ It seems like there is a bug here. I can show different images for each point but can't do that on a hover point. Also when I look at the api I see that highcharts don't provide symbol option for hover : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.states.hover

Comment: Yes i think too : http://jsfiddle.net/km67w/42/
Symbol is not taken into account in the third point of the third serie. Right for the API, i thought that symbol was defined at the marker level and was the same for over.

Comment: can we give the local path to the image in url? I tried it but not appearing on chart.